# "Server execution failed" and "Duplicates not allowed" messages after upgrade to Delphi 10.2.3

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I've just had to update my *RAD Studio 10.2.0 Tokyo* installation to *10.2.3*, so that I could set the `TRESTClient.SecureProtocols` property to `[THTTPSecureProtocol.TLS12]` to enforce TLS 1.2 usage for a third-party web API, but I've run into problems with my other 10.2 applications.

Running a different program in the IDE, which built fine, there is a startup process where it needs to instantiate an object from a COM library dll using `CreateComObject`. This throws a **"Server execution failed"** error.

Rebuilding that COM library in the new *10.2.3* and registering it again using `Regsvr32` resolved the problem, but then the next part of the startup process loads a library using `LoadLibrary`, and that threw a **"Duplicates not allowed"** error.

Again, rebuilding that non-COM library in *10.2.3* resolves the problem, but then I run into the same **"Server execution failed**" error when I try to instantiate an object on a COM server exe rather than library. Rebuilding that EXE resolved the problem.

I was also seeing a **"Runtime error 217"** when using Winapi.Windows.CreateProcess to start an EXE built using *10.2.0*. Rebuilding that EXE in *10.2.3* fixes the error.

There doesn't seem to be any difference in the `System.Win.ComObj.pas` or `Winapi.Windows.pas` between *10.2.0* and *10.2.3*, so what the heck is going on? Why am I needing to rebuild all these other projects?

More importantly, what's going to happen if I need to use a COM library/server or a dynamic link library that's not mine? What about other third-party developers who use our libraries in their own programs? Is it all going to suddenly stop working?

EDIT:

It must be to do with the *RAD Studio* installation, as I now get **"Runtime error 217"** messages for every *10.2.0* program I have, that prior to the upgrade all worked fine, and some of these programs use the `OutputDebugString` to immediately write to the debugger, and I'm not seeing anything at all in *DebugView*.

EDIT:

After reinstalling *10.2.0* all the **"Runtime error 217"** messages disappeared.

Comment: What are the COM and non-COM libraries you talk about? What do you mean by "rebuild" those libraries? Those libraries are yours and you have all the source code to recreate the binaries? If yes, I suggest you debug those libraries to see why they crash because "server execution failed" means the libraries crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a stuffed up install of *10.2.3*. After restarting my machine and reinstalling *10.2.3*, the **217** errors went away, even without rebuilding any of the other programs.

What I really disliked though was that, using either the ISO or the web installer, I am forced to uninstall the *10.2.0* build and therefore lose all of the package information. Takes me 3 hours to rebuild and reinstall all the packages required for our product suites.

I guess that's just par-for-the-course, as there could have been breaking changes in *Update 3* that stopped these packages from working.